# Magento 2 - Get product main image without loading the whole product

Tags: magento2, product-list, performance

I'm trying to load the product images of related products on the category list.phtml without loading the complete product model (to increase performance).

My current code in `list.phtml` is this:

```
 <?php $relatedProducts = $_product->getRelatedProducts(); ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($relatedProducts)): ?>
                    <div class="left-carousel">
                        <div class="product-small-thumbs">
                            <div class="carousel carousel-<?php $_product->getId()?>">
                                <?php $i = 0 ?>
                                <?php foreach($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct): ?>
                                    <?php $i++ ?>
                                    <?php if($i < 5): ?>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                    <?php
                                    $relatedProductId = $relatedProduct->getId();
                                    $relatedProduct = $block->getProductById($relatedProductId);
                                    $resizedImageBig = $block->resizeImage($relatedProduct, 'product_base_image', 460, 460)->getUrl();
                                    $resizedImageSmall = $block->resizeImage($relatedProduct, 'product_base_image', 90, 90)->getUrl();
                                    $relatedProductUrl = $relatedProduct->getUrlKey();
                                    ?>
                                        <img data-id="smallthumbs-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>"
                                         data-img="<?php echo $resizedImageBig; ?>" data-img_def=""
                                         src="<?php echo $resizedImageSmall; ?>"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Notice the getproductbyId function which loads the complete product:

```
public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

Is there away to avoid loading the complete product? I think that my current code is bad for performance. The preferred way would be to only load the resized/cached product main image.

**Solution**
I've used @Sohel Rana answer to solve this problem and this worked very good. However this didn't give me the resized/cached images, so I used a separate module for this: staempfli/magento2-module-image-resizer

You can find it here: https://packagist.org/packages/staempfli/magento2-module-image-resizer

Final code:

```
<?php $resizerHelper = $block->getImageResizerHelper(); ?>
<?php $relatedProducts = $_product->getRelatedProducts(); ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($relatedProducts)): ?>
                    <div class="left-carousel">
                        <div class="product-small-thumbs">
                            <div class="carousel carousel-<?php $_product->getId()?>">
                                <?php $i = 0 ?>
                                <?php foreach($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct): ?>
                                    <?php $i++ ?>
                                    <?php if($i < 5): ?>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                    <?php
                                    $relatedProductId = $relatedProduct->getId();
                                    $images = $block->getImageFromDB($relatedProductId);
                                    $first_image = $images[0]['image'];
                                    $first_image_url = $block->getFullImageUrl($first_image);
                                    $resized_image_large = $resizerHelper->resizeAndGetUrl($first_image_url, 460, 460);
                                    $resized_image_small = $resizerHelper->resizeAndGetUrl($first_image_url, 90, 90);
                                    $relatedProductUrl = $relatedProduct->getUrlKey();
                                    ?>
                                        <img data-id="smallthumbs-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>"
                                         data-img="<?php echo $resized_image_large ?>" data-img_def=""
                                         src="<?php echo $resized_image_small ?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;

}
```

And now:

```
$productId = 2;
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select()
    ->from('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value', '*')
    ->join(
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery',
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.value_id=catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value_id',
        array('image' => 'value')
    )
    ->where('entity_id = ?', $productId);

$images = $connection->fetchAll($select);
echo '<pre>';print_r($images);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: good idea!!!!..

Comment: @Sohel Rana this works great, thanks! What do you think about fetching the direct product image url (example: /media/catalog/product/k/a/ka5599gd.jpg) and not the cached/resized image url?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Sohel's answer you could use the `getMediaGallery` method from `Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product` and if needed modify it to fit your needs:

```
/**
 * Prepare products media gallery
 *
 * @param  int[] $productIds
 * @return array
 */
protected function getMediaGallery(array $productIds)
{
    if (empty($productIds)) {
        return [];
    }
    $select = $this->_connection->select()->from(
        ['mgvte' => $this->_resourceModel->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity')],
        [
            "mgvte.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()}",
            'mgvte.value_id'
        ]
    )->joinLeft(
        ['mg' => $this->_resourceModel->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery')],
        '(mg.value_id = mgvte.value_id)',
        [
            'mg.attribute_id',
            'filename' => 'mg.value',
        ]
    )->joinLeft(
        ['mgv' => $this->_resourceModel->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value')],
        '(mg.value_id = mgv.value_id AND mgv.store_id = 0)',
        [
            'mgv.label',
            'mgv.position',
            'mgv.disabled'
        ]
    )->where(
        "mgvte.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} IN (?)",
        $productIds
    );

    $rowMediaGallery = [];
    $stmt = $this->_connection->query($select);
    while ($mediaRow = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $rowMediaGallery[$mediaRow[$this->getProductEntityLinkField()]][] = [
            '_media_attribute_id' => $mediaRow['attribute_id'],
            '_media_image' => $mediaRow['filename'],
            '_media_label' => $mediaRow['label'],
            '_media_position' => $mediaRow['position'],
            '_media_is_disabled' => $mediaRow['disabled'],
        ];
    }

    return $rowMediaGallery;
}
```

It takes an array of product ids as the only parameter, thus you can call that method before your loop with all your product ids and get the related media galleries.